# Is there any result, that says that $\lfloor e^{n} \rfloor$ is never a prime for $n>2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there any result, that says that $\lfloor e^{n} \rfloor$ is never a prime for $n > 2$ ?

Comment: $\lfloor e^{18} \rfloor = 65659969$ is a prime.

Comment: @achillehui Can I ask how you checked that? Did you just quickly write some code, check a website, or is there a remarkable insight hidden in your answer?

Comment: @smarski I just use a computer algebra system (maxima in my case) to compute the first few terms. Whenever one see a claim like this, the first thing one should do is check the obvious cases before one investing time to prove it.

Comment: There is no known formula to generate a prime number with a computational complexity of O(1).

Comment: @achillehui And the obvious cases are the first several dozen?

Comment: @sasha, Whatever that doesn't take too long to type and too long to run. In this case, the first several dozen.

Answer (score 21):

The counterexamples up to 1000 are:

```
18, 50, 127, 141, 267, 310
```

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A050808.

Answer (score 8):

There is no such result, because $\lfloor e^{18} \rfloor = 65659969$ is prime. This is the smallest counterexample.

Answer (score 7):

Nope for $n=18$ we have

$$\lfloor \exp(18)\rfloor =65659969$$ 
which is prime

The counterexamples for $n\leq 10000$ you have
\begin{array}{c}
18\\
50\\
127\\
141\\
267\\
310\\
2290\\
4487\\
5391\\
\end{array}

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A050808.

Comment: Typo of 8 instead of 18 in your list I believe.

Comment: @Chris in fact I wrote 18 but forgot to center the array so he took the 1 as the positioning letter (r,l,c)